# How to format LocalDate to the standard format for the user's location?

Tags: java, localization, formatting, date-formatting, localdate

How can I format a `LocalDate` based on the standard of the user's location. I want people in the U.S. to see "6/28/2018" while people in Europe to see "28/6/2018" and people in China to see "2018/6/28".

Do I need to use `DateTimeFormatter formatter = ...` or would I need to use something else?

I will also need to convert a string to a `LocalDate` based on the standards of the user's location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do is to use [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) factory method which returns a locale specific date format for the ISO chronology.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL);
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // 2018-10-05
String txt = fmt.format(now); // Friday, 5 October 2018
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse(txt, fmt); // 2018-10-05
```

Comment: It’s not only one way to do it, it is also the good way (as in *the* good way).